# gnupg 'libgpg-error.so.0 no version information available'

Tags: linux, debian, gpg

I'm trying to compile gnupg-2.1.0 for Debian Wheezy, I've downloaded and compiled the required libraries (`libgpg-error-1.17`, `libgcrypt-1.6.2`, `libksba-1.3.2`, `libassuan-2.1.3`, and `pth-2.0.7` in that order) via `./configure`, `make`, `make install`. I then added `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then ran `ldconfig` so that gnupg could find the libraries.

Gpupg compiles fine but upon attempting to run either `./agent/gpg-agent` or `./g10/g` I am greated with this error:

```
alpha@virtual:~/gnupg-2.1.0$ ./agent/gpg-agent --version
./agent/gpg-agent: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by ./agent/gpg-agent)
./agent/gpg-agent: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so.20)
./agent/gpg-agent: relocation error: ./agent/gpg-agent: symbol gpgrt_set_alloc_func, version GPG_ERROR_1.0 not defined in file libgpg-error.so.0 with link time reference
```

`ldd ./agent/gpg-agent` produces

```
root@virtual:/home/alpha/gnupg-2.1.0# ldd ./agent/gpg-agent
./agent/gpg-agent: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by ./agent/gpg-agent)
./agent/gpg-agent: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so.20)
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7750000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/local/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 (0xb7698000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb7694000)
        libassuan.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libassuan.so.0 (0xb7681000)
        libnpth.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libnpth.so.0 (0xb767d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7664000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb74ff000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb74f6000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7751000)
```

Why is this error occuring and how could I fix it?

## Resolution

Resolved by adding /usr/local/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH via `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` and `echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf`

Comment: what does `ldd ./agent/gpg-agent` say?

Comment: You must rebuild all your packages. Try to manipulate the LDFLAGS similar to this stackoverflow answer: [Set rpath at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9625410/436063)

Comment: `ldd ./agent/gpg-agent` produces [this](http://pastebin.com/1qwWMEXz). I'll try rebuilding them all now.

Comment: Do not pastebin, update your question. Try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ldd ./agent/gpg-agent`. If that does not give you the unresolved symbol error at the top, then my proposed solution should work.

Comment: Resolved following your advice along with [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-set-ld_library_path-684799/).

Answer (score 4):

**Root cause of problem**

The error is occurring because at compile time, it is properly searching the `/usr/local/lib` path before it is searching the system default path, thus at link time, all symbols resolve. However at runtime, your `/usr/local/lib` path is not searched before the pre-existing `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` so it is finding the identically named library in the latter directory before your desired library in `/usr/local/lib`.

**Solution, easy version: Global library search path (with caveat)**

The easy version is to insert `/usr/local/lib` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable or `/etc/ld.so.conf` config then run `ldconfig`. For the "fast" solution, you want `/usr/local/lib` before anything else.

However, this is the unfortunate bit, you do **not** want to force all of your programs to search `/usr/local/lib` before the system library path (eg: `/lib/i386-linux-gnu`) -- this makes it highly likely you will cause a version conflict with a system library used by another program provided by your system or package manager and cause the system program to fail. This means to "do things right", you do not want to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD` or `/etc/ld.so.conf` to force your search path. (*In fact, `LD_PRELOAD` should be avoided outside of development work*)

**Solution, stable version: Update ELF RPATH**

Instead, when compiling your own versions of applications, you can use the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable (gnu ld & gold) or setting `LDFLAGS` to `-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib` to manage the internal library-search-path of your binaries (including .so shared library dependencies)

So for example, you could run the following to configure your library:

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
./configure --prefix=/usr/local <--yourflags>
make install
```

My experience with this technique has been on HP-UX where the `chatr` utility will show you the embedded rpath (and the link flag is `+b` instead of -rpath). `readelf` or `objdump` will probably show the rpath on linux.

[patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html) claims to be able to update the rpath in existing binaries on linux x86, but I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems with Ubuntu (12 and 14 and 16, Gnome and Xfce, completely different machines ....) and 
I compiled the whole stuff from scratch. Interesting, does not help at all. same errors: Version 2 required, no communication with pinentry and so on.

Removed the old 1.4 - stupid mistake! They are designed to co-exist (1.x and 2.x).

The solution actually was this: 
Do install gnupg2 with the Ubuntu CLI:

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg2
```

did the job. 
With all 4 machines and all Versions. 
So simple, so cool. Works like a charm :-)
SOLVED (at least on my zoo of installations)

Answer (score 0):

For me, in the distant past, I had built and installed to /usr/local(lib and bin) which shadowed the new release. Easily solved by checking /usr/local for the shadow executables and libraries and then run ldconfig and hash -r.

Answer (score 0):

There was already a previous installation of **gnupg 2.2.x** on my machine, and when I tried to install the latest **gnupg 2.4.x**, I ran into this error (during **make check**). The solution was to uninstall (and clean) the previous version and then building the latest version.